# Recovery mode - nothing is done

Tags: recovery-mode

I'm very new in Ubuntu, so any help will be appreciated.
I've tried to enter to Recovery mode and to fix my files system. I got the message below:

```
Continuing will remount your  / filesystem in read/write mode and
mount any other filesystem filesystem defined in /ect/fstab. Do you
wish to continue ?
```

I clicked yes, but then - nothing is done! I saw no process status...

What do I have to do?

Comment: This will just remount your FS an nothing else. This is it. What else should happen? What do you expect?

Comment: Your file system has been remounted then.  If not you would have received an error.  By default the file system is mounted read only in recovery mode and you need to remount it so you can make changes.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I think that the system should report me if the operation succeeded\failed. is it ok that I dint get any message? and what do I have to do now - press esc and exit from this window?

Comment: Mount actions normaly doesent report an OK but it report an error. Your FS should be mounted writable. Now you can go on with what you want to do. I dont now what do you have to do because you dont tell us what you want or what you have done so far.

Comment: I got “serious errors while checking the disk drives for /boot” error while booting - and I 've tried to fix this by booting to the safemode. I've tried to fix it by pressing M - but I cannot succeeded since I dont know what is the the root password (I've tried to type the sudo password, but probably the root password is diffrent from my sudo password). I will appreciet if you can help me with any advice - thanks!